# Trigger missing dependencies in (parallel) GNU make by changing order of execution

Tags: gnu-make

Suppose I have a Makefile:

```
a.out:
    sleep 3
    touch a.out a1

b.out:
    cat a1 > b.out

c.out: a.out b.out
    cat a.out b.out > c.out
```

`make c.out` will *usually* succeed, as the commands for a.out are executed before the commands for b.out.  But `make b.out` will fail (in a clean directory), as will `make -j c.out`.

As in real-life scenarios there is seldomly a `sleep 3` and the bug will thus only show very randomly, I'm looking for a way to smoke out such errors with a higher probability.  One idea would be to reverse the order of execution for targets "on the same level": As the test suite will usually trigger first generation of a.out, then b.out, if instead first b.out was generated, the bug would surface.

Is there a way in GNU make to do this?

Comment: `make b.out` (in a clean directory) will fail quite reliably. The solution (`b.out: a.out`) will solve the `c.out` failure. So what's the problem?

Comment: @Beta What the question says: How to find those errors with a higher probability so that `make -j` will not give schrödinbugs.

Comment: The OP question would be better phrased "How to discover unstated dependencies between the dependencies of a target in GNU `make`?"

Answer (score 2):

Paul Smith replied on [help-make@gnu.org](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.make.general/10602) that this is not possible with current GNU make.

Answer (score 0):

The single re-ordering of the target dependencies that is most likely to reveal unstated dependencies between the dependencies of a target is the **reverse ordering** of the target dependencies.

You can achieve the reverse ordering by testing the `Makefile` with a conditionally executed dependency section such as:

```
a.out: b.out
```

For longer dependency lists this would be:

```
a.out: b.out
b.out: d.out
d.out: e.out
:
:
```